# Radio button turns value 0 when only values 1,2,3,4,5 are available

Tags: html, null, radio-button, rating, zero

one item can have a rating of 1,2,3,4, or 5, but in database there are some rating with value "0". I dont know how it got there.Any suggestions, this is the code:

```
 <div class="yourRating">
<input type="hidden" value="269" id="userLoggedCheck" />
<div class="yourRatingDiv">
<div class="yourRatingText">your rating </div>
<input name="notLoggedRate" id="notLoggedRate1" type="radio" title="1 Yll" value="1"  class="star"  />
<input name="notLoggedRate" id="notLoggedRate2" type="radio" title="2 Yje" value="2"   class="star"  />
<input name="notLoggedRate" id="notLoggedRate3" type="radio" title="3 Yje" value="3"  class="star" />
<input name="notLoggedRate" id="notLoggedRate4" type="radio" title="4 Yje" value="4"  class="star"  />
<input name="notLoggedRate" id="notLoggedRate5" type="radio" title="5 Yje" value="5" class="star"  >


</div>

<div class="userNotLoggedInDiv" style="display:none; left:228px; top:-5px;">
<img src="images/rightArrow.png" class="leftArrowClass4" height="24" width="9" alt="Object Pointer" />
<img src="images/close2.jpg" class="leftArrowClass5" height="13" width="13" alt="Close" />

<div class="notLoggedText">log in to rate</div>

    <a href="login" class="userLogInHref">Log in</a>

<div class="haventSignUpYet">Still not registered <a href="register" class="userSignUpHref"> register now <img src="images/setupLink.png" class="setupLinkImg" alt="Icon" /></a></div>
<div class="space"></div>
</div></div>
```

Comment: What happens if I don't click any radio button? 0 default?

Answer (score 0):

Not really enough information here, you do not show whether you are fetching from or posting to the DB or how you are doing it – but guessing with the little data you did provide, you do not have a default radio selected, so saving the data without making a choice would send a null through  …which a db int will convert to 0